# Function execution order - cpp

Tags: c++, function

The following code

```
void function(char* p1, char* p2)
{
    // [...]
    return;
}
char* print(char* msg)
{
    printf("%s\n", msg);
    return msg;
}
function(print("first"), print("second"));
```

gives output like this:
second
first

I'm curious why its executing functions from right to left.

Comment: The standard does not specify the order of parameter evaluation, it is up to the vendor to implement this

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934904/order-of-evaluation-in-c-function-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ standard, **Function call (5.2.2/4)**, says:

> When a function is called, each parameter shall be initialized with its corresponding argument. [ *Note*: Such initializations are indeterminately sequenced with respect to each other — *end note* ]

Your compiler, for that piece of code chose to initialize the parameters in right to left order. Presented with different code, or even the same code, your compiler could make a different choice. The order is simply unspecified by the standard and you cannot rely on it.

If you wish to enforce a particular order you must sequence these function calls explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

This Problem is because of Stack Memory used by the function.

`function(print("first"), print("second"));`

the execution of this function will be as follows:

```
// Push Operation
1. Call function()
2. Call print("First")
3. Call Print("Second")

// Pop Operation

4. Execute Print("Second")
5. Execute Print("First")
6. Execute function()
```

Because of this the output is `Second First`.

For More Information You Can Refer [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21300760/3110262).

Hope this will Help you to Understand